# Differences between termFilter anh mustFilter in, shouldFilter and orFilter in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

## Differences between termFilter anh mustFilter in, shouldFilter and orFilter in Elasticsearch?

> Someone tell me ??? I think no differences .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Term Filter**

The term filter is used to filter by exact values, be they numbers, dates, Booleans, or not_analyzed exact-value string fields:

> { "term": { "age":    26           }} { "term": { "date":
>   "2014-09-01" }} { "term": { "public": true         }} { "term": {
>   "tag":    "full_text"  }}

**Bool Filter**

The bool filter is composed of three sections:

> {    "bool" : {
>         "must" :     [],
>         "should" :   [],
>         "must_not" : [],    } }

**must**

All of these clauses must match. The equivalent of AND.

**must_not**

All of these clauses must not match. The equivalent of NOT.

**should**

At least one of these clauses must match. The equivalent of OR.
And that’s it! When you need multiple filters, simply place them into the different sections of the bool filter.

Check the following  link  it may be helpful:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_most_important_queries_and_filters.html

Comment: I want ask if i use must[] compare And[] , should[] compare or[] what differences?

Answer (score 0):

**Must Filter**:

Must Filter is same like boolean 'AND' operator and within the must clause it must retrieve.

**Should Filter**: It is like boolean 'OR' operator and at least one should clause must execute if 'MUST' clause is not present.

**Term Filter**: It is basically used to take exact values such as numbers, dates and not_analyzed fields.